# Story where humanity is sterile, except a few young women

Tags: story-identification

This is a story I read at least 20 years ago, I think.

- There is a group of young, pregnant women on a space station (or a moon base?).
- There are no children on Earth and all humans have become sterile - everybody is old
- The main protagonist is tasked with bringing the pregnant women to Earth where they will be used to breed the new humanity
- He doesn't go where he is supposed to, but takes them to some isolated island
- Another thing I remember is that they are in something like a space shuttle, being pursued by one or two, very elderly fighter pilots, which he manages to shake off.

Now that I've been asked about the pilot's motivation, I remember a bit more: The women had been sent to the space station to protect them from the... (virus?) that made everybody on Earth sterile. Now there are only old people left, and they are consumed by a desire to see children - they want to bring the women back to use them in an intensive breeding programme, basically keeping them prisoners and forcing them though constant pregnancy until they are worn out. The pilot wants to hinder this.

That is all I remember at the moment - I think it was a shortish story. Any idea?

Comment: I kinda want to say Children of Men but I've never watched it myself so I'd be guessing...

Comment: No, not that one - one more thing I remember is a space shuttle; I'll add it in an edit

Comment: It's like someone went riffing on Vonnegut's *Galápagos*.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the pilot's motives for disobeying his orders? For instance, does he hope to keep these women as a personal harem, or does he simply think he is protecting them from whoever currently runs the government? (So they won't become that guy's slaves, for instance?)

Comment: @Lorendiac I've edited my post with my reply.

Comment: If we're talking about the current International Space Station or even another it would be the last place genetically viable females should go because of the radiation. Until a viable radiation shield is in place you risk making the only viable females sterile themselves.

Comment: @tgrignon I'm sure this would have been sorted out with a bit of hand-waving, the most powerful technology known to science (-fiction).

Comment: @j4nd3r53n I'm glad I was able to stir your memory with my question. I was hoping the pilot's motives were pure, rather than extremely self-centered, but it could have gone either way. (Poul Anderson once wrote a story where the heroine finally realized that an officer on a passenger liner had intended for a lifeboat with 4 beautiful women, 2 alien passengers who didn't care about human sexuality, and himself as the sole eligible bachelor, to all be "accidentally stranded" on an Earthlike planet where he'd have those lovely women all to himself. It didn't work out the way he had hoped.)